# Draft / Live Content System Database Design

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I've been working on a project that requires draft/live versions of content and have thought of a design such as below:

```
Article
    ID
    Creator
    CreationDate
    DraftContent(fk to ArticleContent)
    PublicContent(fk to ArticleContent)
    IsPendingApproval

ArticleContent
    Title
    Body
```

I am wondering if it would be better to change the foreign keys upon an article being published or if it is better to just copy the contents from the draft table to the live table.

Any suggestions?

Edit: Both draft and live versions exist at once although the live version is the only one that is visible to the public. There can only be one draft and one live table

Part of the reason for this design is to force users to have their articles approved before they go live.

Update:

We decided to use Kieren's solution with a slight modification. Instead of using a column for items like IsPublished IsLive we decided to use a single state column. Otherwise the design remained the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Draft articles that become live and then are 'published'**

The usual thing would be to have a status/type flag on the article table - `IsLive`.

Using separate tables is unnecessary and redundant; changing foreign keys doesn't make much sense either.  Think of the article as a valid object, whether its draft or live.  The only difference is, in *most* cases you only want to display live articles.  In some cases in the future, you might want to display both.

**Articles that might be edited and have a new draft version after initially becoming live**

In terms of one article having both a live and draft version - the most common pattern would be to have a master `Article` entity/object, and then say `ArticleVersion` coming from that.  The `ArticleVersion` would have the `IsLive` property, or even better, the `Article` itself would have a property, `CurrentLiveVersionId`.  That way there can be a live and draft versions lying around, but you'd only usually join `Article` onto the `ArticleVersion` by that `CurrentLiveVersionId` to get the current live version.

Advantages of having the `ArticleVersion` table include the fact that the entire history of an article, a changelog, can be stored, so you can revert to previous versions if needed, or review changes.  All for a very low implementation cost..

Let me know if I can clarify this method.

Comment: +1, the "single table of articles, with separate table of content" is really the way to fly here.

Comment: Potentially very easy - each ArticleVersion would have an ApprovedBy / ApprovedDate, it it can't be set to the current version if that's null (in the business logic) ?

Comment: Instead of having a version number would it not be better to do a revision date and creation date for the version row? That way users can revise drafts until the sun goes down and it shows up only a different version when the page is published?

Comment: IDs are pretty important in RDBs.  There is no 'version number' per se but I even think that should exist.  Rather than a CurrentLiveVersionId, if you're relying on dates, you could have a `PublishDate` on each version, and then when displaying an article, retrieve the article with the first `PublishDate` older than right-now that is approved (approved being the important bit).

Comment: Problem with this design is how you're supposed to keep old drafts straight? If you have a foreign key in the master article table pointing to a single version record, should you have foreign keys in each version that point back to the master article?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that was supposed to be implicit from the "Article entity/object, and then say ArticleVersion coming from that" - there's a relationship there, and it would be one-to-many, i.e. FK in the version entity :)

Comment: @WyattBarnett  and Kieren - Why are separate draft/live tables redundant? They are efficient from a search point of view. If you have a full text index on the table - then imagine the relative overhead caused by drafts in the same table.

Comment: @Walt -- Presuming your articles aren't book-length and you've got a reasonably intelligent indexing system the FT overhead should be minimal.

Comment: (This is from 3 years ago so bear with me).. Create an index on the table on the IsLive column.  Any overhead immediately gone.  The redudancy is you have two tables to store objects with an identical schema.  Anything you want to do, you have to do in two places.  The definition of redundancy

Comment: How to deal when the article has a unique key like slug, you cannot save 2 object with the same slug on the same table.

Comment: This needs to be drawn out with tables and is incredibly confusing!

Answer (score 1):

Your design looks appropriate to me.  When a new version goes live, I would:

1. `UPDATE` the `PublicContent` key to point to the (formerly) draft article.
2. `DELETE` the no-longer-referenced formerly-published article.
3. `NULL` the DraftContent key or, if your model calls for *always* having a draft version, `INSERT` a new, empty draft into `ArticleContent` and point the `DraftContent` key to it.